# GLSL shader performance reduced by loop?

Tags: opengl, glsl, performance, gpu

I hav a fragment shader like this:

```
#version 330 core

in vec4 v_color;
in vec2 v_texCoords[10];

out vec4 frag_color;

uniform int actual_textures;
uniform sampler2D u_texture[10];

void main() {
    vec4 final_color = texture(u_texture[0], v_texCoords[0]);
    for(int i = 1; i < actual_textures; i++){
        vec4 tex = texture(u_texture[i], v_texCoords[i]);
        final_color = tex * tex.a + final_color * (1 - tex.a);
    }

    frag_color = v_color * final_color;
}
```

But somehow this slows my game down by 30 - 40fps in comparison to this approach:

```
#version 330 core

in vec4 v_color;
in vec2 v_texCoords[10];

out vec4 frag_color;

uniform sampler2D u_texture[10];

void main() {
    vec4 final_color = texture(u_texture[0], v_texCoords[0]);
    vec4 tex = texture(u_texture[1], v_texCoords[1]);
    final_color = tex * tex.a + final_color * (1 - tex.a);
    tex = texture(u_texture[2], v_texCoords[2]);
    final_color = tex * tex.a + final_color * (1 - tex.a);
    //...

    frag_color = v_color * final_color;
}
```

Why does a single loop slow the gpu down so much?

Comment: Are you sure you're iterating `actual_textures` times in the non-loop approach?

Comment: yes, both times actual_textures is 3

Comment: What graphics card are you using? The GLSL compiler for your driver should be unrolling that loop.

Comment: @Honeybunch would it be able to unroll it when `actual_textures` is a `uniform int` variable that could change between draw calls? Adapting to a change in its value would require a recompile to unroll to a different number of iterations, so I think the compiler would be forced to leave the loop loopy.

Comment: Oh that's a good point. A good test would be to hard code the range of the loop and see if that gives performance back.

Comment: Sorry but I already tried that. It doesn't matter if it's hard coded or an uniform int. Fps stays the same.
@Honeybunch I use an Intel HD 3000

Comment: Do you have a machine with a dedicated card to test? Or even just any other machine with some other GPU? I suspect you've hit some oddity with the Intel driver's GLSL compiler

Comment: even on a "weak" laptop with amd graphics, the slowdown is noticable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered this issue when implementing other shader types with certain hardware configurations.

I believe the issue lies with `texture(u_texture[i], v_texCoords[i]);` : because the graphics hardware performs prefetch on texture units, it needs to be able to predict to some degree what it will be fetching, or you experience performance drop similar to a cache miss.

Unrolling the loop allows the code to perform the prefetch properly, allowing for a higher framerate.